# Is it possible to print a photo from Picasa Web Albums?

Tags: picasa-web-albums

In Picasa Web albums I can print the entire page, or download the photo and print.
But is it possible to print the photo directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If not *directly*, the following workaround may work for you:

1. Navigate to the image in Picasa, so that you're viewing a single photo with navigation arrows on each side
2. Click the *Full screen* button
3. Right-click on the image, and:

   - In Chrome or Firefox: Click *Copy image address*
   - In Internet Explorer: Click *Properties*, and select the URL address
   - In Safari: Don't have a Mac right now, but a similar option exists
4. Click on the browser's location bar, selecting the text already there
5. Type Ctrl+V (or Command-V on Macs) to paste the image address, and press Enter
6. The image is displayed in the browser - type Ctrl-P (Command-P) to print it

Comment: Thanks, works pretty well. Can resize using print preview too. Note you can jump from step 2 to step 6 and I think you get the same result.

Comment: Oh yeah, that might be possible. I wasn't sure if you were seeing the full-size version of the image in step 1.